# NServiceBus 4.03, when the queue doesnt exist, message is being sent to Transaction Dead Letter Q

Tags: queue, msmq, transactional, nservicebus4, dead-letter

I have Distributor/Worker model.

Machine A - Distributor

Machine B - Worker

When the worker B is trying the send message to Distributor on a wrong Q name, its putting the message into Transactional Dead Letter Q.

I was expecting the message to delivered to error q.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior.

NServiceBus uses the error queue when the processing of an *incoming* message fails.

This is not the same as trying to send a message to a queue which does not exist.

There maybe an exception to this is if the message send is performed from inside a handler, though I have not tested this scenario.